# How to get the DevlRefExpr operand out of UnaryOperator in the Clang LLVM AST?

Tags: c++, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-c++-api

I have this code here:

```
class MemcpyMatcher : public MatchFinder::MatchCallback
{
  public:
    MemcpyMatcher(map<string, Replacements> * replacements)
        : replacements(replacements) {}
    /* Callback method for the MatchFinder.
     * @param result - Found matching results.
     */
    virtual void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult& result)
    {
        const CallExpr* call_expr = result.Nodes.getNodeAs<CallExpr>("memcpy_call");
        if (call_expr != NULL) {
            const Expr* voidp_dest = call_expr->getArg(0)->IgnoreImplicit();
            const Expr* voidp_src  = call_expr->getArg(1)->IgnoreImplicit();
            const Expr* size_t_n   = call_expr->getArg(2)->IgnoreImplicit();

            voidp_dest->dump();
    }

  private:
    map<string, Replacements>* replacements;
    // Add other variables here as needed.
};
```

This is the output of the `voidp_dest->dump();` statement:

```
UnaryOperator 0x2148d48 'int *' prefix '&'
`-DeclRefExpr 0x2148cf8 'int' lvalue Var 0x21480c0 'number' 'int'
```

In the source code, the expression that I'm grabbing looks like this: `&number`.

I want to get the `DeclRefExpr` out of the `UnaryOperator`, in order to turn it into a string and get the name of the variable out. I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

For anybody who is still searching for answer:

```
  const DeclRefExpr* decl_ref = nullptr;
  if (auto unary = dyn_cast<UnaryOperator>(expr)) {
    if (unary->getOpcode() == UnaryOperator::Opcode::UO_AddrOf) {
      unsigned count = 0;
      // there will be only one child
      for (auto child : unary->children()) {
        decl_ref = dyn_cast<DeclRefExpr>(child);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this same task with less LOC,

```
DeclRefExpr* ref = nullptr;
if(auto UnOp = dyn_cast<UnaryOperator>(expr)) {
  ref = dyn_cast<DeclRefExpr>(UnOp->getSubExp());
}
```